# function not being executed C

Tags: c, function, while-loop, switch-statement

So I have an `IsNumber()` function which checks if an user input is a number or not, if it isn't the the program stops, however the function just isn't working for some reason.

Here is where it's implemented:

```
bool IsNumber(const char* pStr);

int main()
{
    int user;
    char decision;
    char * str[256] = {user};
    bool valid;

    scanf("%d",&user);

    clear_stdin(); // function to remove

    sprintf(str, "%d", user); // to convert input into string so to validate number with function IsNumber

    valid = IsNumber(str);

    if (valid == false)
    {
        printf("Entered input is not a number, exiting now.");
        exit(1);
    }
 }
```

And here is the function itself:

```
bool IsNumber(const char* pStr)
{
    if(NULL == pStr || *pStr == "\0")
        return false;

    int dotCount = 0;
    int plusCount = 0;
    int minusCount = 0;

    while (*pStr)
    {
        char c = *pStr;
        switch(c)
        {
        case '.':
             if (++dotCount > 1)
                return false;
             break;
        case '-':
            if (++minusCount > 1)
                return false;
             break;
        case '+':
            if (++plusCount > 1)
               return false;
        default:
            if (c < '0' || c > '9')
                return false;
         }
        pStr++;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: What do you expect to be in `user` when a number is not entered?

Comment: @stark it does not matter. There will be the valid number

Comment: `char * str[256] = { user };` - I strongly suspect that is wrong from inception. Turn up your compiler warnings. The later code using `str` as if it is `char []` and not its actual `char *[]` self (such as the target of a `sprintf`) is a fairly pungent aroma.

Comment: If `scanf("%d",&user)` [returns](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf#Return_value) `1` it's guaranteed that the user entered an integer number, you don't need to convert it to a string and use a second check.

Comment: You are converting a string to a number then back to a string to test if its a number.

Comment: How do you know it does not run? Learn how to debug and create a [mre]

Comment: You want to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57842756/why-should-i-always-enable-compiler-warnings) before you write another line of C code.

Comment: Most occurrences of `’+’` are not a digit; you forgot the `break;` after the plus case.  Always add the break, even after the last case label in the switch.  Also note that you shouldn't accept plus or minus except as the first (none-space?) character.

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with your code:

The line

```
char *str[256] = {user};
```

You are declaring an `array` of 256 pointers to `char`, none of them is initialized along your code, so they point to nothing, furthermore you are trying to assign an `int` variable to a `char` pointer.

The line

```
sprintf(str, "%d", user);
```

`str` is not a valid argument, you could use `str[0]`, but, again, `str[0]` points to nowhere.

The line

```
if(NULL == pStr || *pStr == "\0")
                            ^^^^
```

You are comparing a single character with a string, a valid comparison would be:

```
if(NULL == pStr || *pStr == '\0')
                            ^^^^
```

Other issues are:

- A missing `break` in `case '+'`.
- `char decision` is never used.

Answer (score 1):

your function does not check for the most of the errors (for example 345+456). You need to remember that some chars can be only at the particular places to make number valid. 
Here you have a bit better one (very simple for the sake of simplicity of the answer).

```
int isNumber(const char *str)
{
    int result = 1;
    int dotFound = 0;
    const char *saved = str;

    if(str || *str)
    {
        while(*str && result)
        {
            if(*str == '-' || *str == '+')
            {
                 if(str != saved) result = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                if(*str == '.') 
                {
                    if(dotFound) result = 0;
                    dotFound = 1;   
                }
                else
                {
                    if(!isdigit(*str)) result = 0;
                }
            }
            str++;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Your test idea is wrong. sprintf will always print a valid int number. it will also never generate the string with the dot '.' inside.

https://godbolt.org/z/d_Bah9

Comment: Following you rational for DV, initialization of the str does not matter in the OPs code and it is not the issue.

Comment: @anastaciu - revenge DV. Lovely

Comment: Well, since I like you answer, I'll give you a revenge UV.